# cookies php curl - false

Tags: php, cookies, curl

Why is it that when I grab a cookie and store it to a file, every line is FALSE/FALSE? I've tried various different ways and still end up with the same thing. What am I missing? And for a clarification, you load one url, it sets a cookie and bounces to another url where that cookie is then read. But I can't even get the cookie to set properly. Here's my code:

```
$cookie_file_path = 'cookie.txt';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
echo $content;
```

EDIT:
So my question is for this post - by receiving FALSE /FALSE - does that mean the cookie isn't set properly?

Answer (score 0):

See http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2005-03/0099.html for a description of the format of the `cookie.txt` file. The columns are:

- domain
- tailmatch
- path
- secure
- expires
- name
- value

`tailmatch` and `secure` are both booleans, so they're either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. So if you see:

```
www.domain.com FALSE / FALSE ...
```

it means:

- `tailmatch = FALSE`
- `path = /` means the cookie applies to all paths in the domain
- `secure = FALSE` means the cookie doesn't require SSL

`tailmatch` is true when the cookie applies to all subdomains of a domain, rather than a specific hostname; the `domain` would then be `.domain.com` rather than something like `www.domain.com`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Does that mean it's not scrapable?

Comment: I never said that. You wanted to know why all the lines in the cookie file contain `FALSE / FALSE`. I explained what those mean.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get the other 4 columns, all you see is `FALSE / FALSE` on every line? I can't reproduce that with my URL.

Comment: Ok, understood. Makes sense. But apparently I am doing something wrong, because it's not allowing me to capture the cookie correctly to be used for the next curl

Comment: here's an example: www.stuller.com FALSE / FALSE 1432060998 cart_session_id 6bfeb4a8-e993-44a9-b844-af3cc70dbff7

Comment: So what's the problem? The name of that cookie is `cart_session_id`, and its values is `6bfeb4a8-e993-44a9-b844‌​-af3cc70dbff7`? The first `FALSE` means that the domain matched exactly, rather than matching the domain. The second `FALSE` means it's not SSL.

Comment: The `/` means that the cookie applies to the root and all subdirectories of the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53993/discussion-between-mrtechie-and-barmar).

Comment: Sorry Barmar, didn't mean to bring you into chat.

Comment: I hate when I accidentally click that, too.

Comment: Here's my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745468/curl-php-setting-cookies-properly