# cURL with specified URLs works, with preg_match URLs fails

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I use a site that stores two cookies (`ASP.NET_SessionID` and `__RequestVerificationToken_XXXXXXXXX`) when you visit it.

The page consists of a div with a link to a pdf and an iframe with a "pdf viewer" source.

I am trying to use cURL to retrieve those two cookies then download the pdf. I have found that I have to set several options in cURL. However, I am still not able to download the pdf.

My setup now is:

1. Hit the main page and (a) save the `ASP.NET_SessionID` cookie, (b) find the "pdf viewer" URL from the iframe, and (c) find the pdf download URL
2. Hit the "pdf viewer" URL and save the `__RequestVerificationToken_XXXXXXXXX` cookie
3. Create the cookie header from steps 1 and 2
4. Download the file using cURL, the pdf download URL, and sending cookie headers

However, my file result is just a login page.

First cURL:

```
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0';
$report_url = "[my_main_url_here]";

$ch1 = curl_init($report_url);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'AES128-SHA:RC2-CBC-MD5');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
$output1 = curl_exec($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);
```

I use `preg_match` to find the pdf download link:

```
preg_match("/\/ReportID=.{30}/", $output1, $pdf_link);
$pdf_viewer_full = "https://gate.aon.com" . $pdf_link[0];
```

Then I hit the pdf viewer URL to get the second cookie:

```
$ch2 = curl_init($viewer_url_full);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'AES128-SHA:RC2-CBC-MD5');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
$output2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);
```

I then pull out the cookies from the headers of both of those:

```
preg_match("/ASP.NET_SessionId=......................../", $output1, $cookie1);
preg_match("/__RequestVerificationToken_.{145}/", $output2, $cookie2);
$cookies = 'Cookie: ' . $cookie1[0] . '; ' . $cookie2[0];
```

And then attempt to download the file:

```
$headers = array ($cookies);
$file = fopen ('Report.pdf', 'w+');
$ch3 = curl_init($pdf_link_full);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'AES128-SHA:RC2-CBC-MD5');
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
$output3 = curl_exec($ch3);
curl_close($ch3);
```

**EDIT:** If I manually set `$pdf_link_full`, it works. However, if I find it with `preg_match` (like above), it fails.

However, if I print `$pdf_link_full` and `$pdf_link_full_2`, they appear as the same exact thing. Am I missing encoding or something else here? Thanks!

Comment: Show your code so we can tell you how to fix the cookie options.

Comment: If you use `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLTOPT_COOKIEJAR`, cURL should take care of receiving and sending the cookies automatically.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745468/curl-php-setting-cookies-properly/23747787#23747787

Comment: Sorry about that. I added code. I commented out the `$headers` and the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: So it turns out the problem is apparently due to my `preg_match`. See my edit.

Comment: I don't see where you're setting `viewer_url_full` or `$pdf_link_full` using `preg_match. You're just setting `$cookies`.

Comment: Sorry, I updated again. When I find `$pdf_link_full` using `preg_match`, it fails. When I declare `$pdf_link_full`, it works. When I print both, they appear as the same exact thing.

Comment: Maybe there's an extra space at the end when you use the regexp? When you print them, you wouldn't notice this.

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to see them with more detail.

Comment: Ahhh, I think the problem was when I manually set it I was using ampersands (&) and preg_match was finding it with &amp;. I didn't think it would matter, but `str_replace` seems to have fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Use `html_entity_decode()` instead of `str_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my `preg_match`. It was returning a URL with `&amp;` and, when I manually set it, I was using just the ampersand (`&`).

Replacing the `&amp;` with `&` resolved the issue.